# Op-amp variable reference voltage

Tags: operational-amplifier, best-practice, biasing

Is it appropriate to trim signal offset to an op-amp using only a divider and a trim-pot? For stable operation would it be preferable to connect drive the potentiometer from precision references or use zener diode shunts to keep the reference voltage independent of supply fluctuations.

Is the 1uF filter cap a good idea to keep this a stable DC reference and filter noise introduced by the divider resistors?

I use this circuit very often and I want to make sure this is the best approach for precision circuitry.

[image: Op-amp offset]

Comment: If the two rails don't track, you get a big error. Check the amplifier temperature coefficient of offset, no point trimming to better than that. A small resistor from each end of the pot to ground references the trim to ground rather than the rails, much better stability even without precision references.

Comment: To answer I have to ask why would you do this trim i.e. Do you perceive some kind of benefit somewhere. The simplistic nature of your circuit gives no clues as to why you might want to trim it.

Comment: Read this free ebook: https://focus.ti.com/lit/an/slod006b/slod006b.pdf  and learn the why and how of opamps and their offset. In your proposed circuit the opamp's offset is really insignificant. I also see no reason why you would even need to compensate for offset with this type of circuit.

Comment: The purpose of the trim is not to compensate for the op-amps offset but to remove a DC offset from the signal so that I can amplify only the AC component. Or to add a variable DC offset to an AC signal for that matter.

Comment: Then why not AC couple the input to the OP-amp?

Comment: Another application would be trimming the setpoint of a PID controller

Comment: @Dejvid_no1 The trouble with AC coupling is that I need AC response down to 1 Hz which would result in the component values getting too large.

Comment: @Mike I'm not on your wavelength on this re the component values getting too large. If you are looking to make the dc gain unity to avoid significant dc offsets in a high gain inverting amplifier configuration then why should component values get too big?

Comment: @Andyaka If I want to AC couple down to 1Hz with say a 1uF ceramic cap then the input resistor needs to be 159kΩ and for a 20dB gain would need a 1.6MΩ feedback resistor. And I can practically only go up another decade on the blocking cap. Unless of course I am missing something, but I am here to learn.

Comment: You can get 47 uF ceramic surface mount capacitors. You can use a self biasing non-inverting input that uses a low pass filter of say 100 kohm and a 2u2 capacitor.

Answer (score 1):

Stability realy depends on the nature of the signal coming in and the offset that you are trying to adjust.

If the incoming offset you are trying to adjust out also tracks the supply rails you are using, this method works pretty well. If however the input signal has a fixed offset generated by some other circuit or device then a fixed reference would be more appropriate.

Basically, the answer is... it depends.

As for the capacitor, some filtering on offset trimmers is often a good idea, especially if the resistors involved are large. However you have to be aware that this capacitor introduces a settling time at power on which may or may not be important to your function.

Comment: So if this reference was used to adjust the setpoint of a PID temperature controller I would probably want to use a bandgap reference, right? This way the temperature would not carry any variations in the supply rails.

Comment: @Mike correct, or any other stable reference or derivative of same you may have already.